# error: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

i want to test to insert data from csv file on spring boot mongodb

but the error say

`readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.`

This is example of data in csv file

[image]

and this my code. The problem is the Document source = Document.parse(a[7])

activityLog.setSource(source)

```
@Test
    public void loadData() throws IOException, MongoException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");

        Files.lines(Path.of("C:\\Users\\syahir\\Desktop\\activity-log-data.csv"))
                .skip(1)
                //.limit(20)
                .map(l -> l.split(","))
                .map(a -> {

                    UUID activityLogId = UUID.fromString(a[0]);
                    String logKey = a[1];
                    String referenceNumber = a[2];
                    ZonedDateTime transactionTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.parse(a[3], formatter);
                    //LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.valueOf(a[4]);
                    String sessionId = a[4];
                    String correlationId = a[5];

                    ActivityLog activityLog = new ActivityLog(
                            activityLogId,
                            logKey,
                            referenceNumber,
                            transactionTimestamp.toLocalDateTime(),
                            sessionId,
                            correlationId
                            );
                    int newActivity = Integer.parseInt(a[6]);
                    Document activity = new Document("", newActivity);
                    activityLog.setActivity(new Document(activity));

                    //String newSource = a[7];
                    Document source = Document.parse(a[7]);
                    activityLog.setSource(source);

                    return activityLog;

                //}).count();
                }).forEach(activityLogRepository::save);
    }
```